# Find the value entered by a color input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to code a very simple color picker but I have been stuck on how to get the value of the color that the user picked into javascript. This is my code:

```
<input type="color" value="#ff0000">
<script>
    const input = document.querySelector("input")
    input.addEventListener("change")
    const color = e.target.value;
    console.log(rgb);
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: log `color` instead of `rgb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a handler function in which you have to get the color:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input")
input.addEventListener("change", function(event){
  const color = event.target.value;
  console.log(color);
});
```

```html
<input type="color" value="#ff0000">
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the color value like this

```
 <input type="color" id="myColor" value="#ff0000">
 var colorval = document.getElementById("myColor").value;
```

Answer (score -1):

There are several issues with your code.

First, I'd add an `id` attribute to your input and use `getElementById()`.

You also need to pass 2 arguments to `addEventListener`, the first one being on what event to trigger (here on `change`) and the second a function which will run when that event occurs. The function takes a parameter `e` (the event) from which you can access `e.target.value` and use it as you wish.

```html
<input id="color-picker" type="color" value="#ff0000">
<script>
    const input = document.getElementById("color-picker")
    input.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
      const color = e.target.value;
      console.log(color);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: To whom it may concern: clarify why the downvote? Did I miss something?